# Postgres Bad Planner Estimates on Join

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-15

I have four tables in a model hierarchy: `customer`, `subscription`, `billing_cycle`, and `product_version`. Every object in that hierarchy has a foreign key to its parent object.

There are a number of indices on all of the conditions used in my queries. `customer` has an index as follows:

```postgresql
CREATE INDEX customer_mrr_index ON public.customer USING btree (integration_id, id) INCLUDE (name, attributes, manual_attributes)
```

`subscription`:

```postgresql
CREATE INDEX subscription_mrr_index ON public.subscription USING btree (integration_id, customer_id, id) INCLUDE (attributes)
```

`billing_cycle`:

```postgresql
CREATE INDEX billing_cycle_mrr_index ON public.billing_cycle USING btree (integration_id, subscription_id, id)
```

`product_version`:

```postgresql
CREATE INDEX pv_mrr_index ON public.product_version USING btree (integration_id, billing_cycle_id, id) INCLUDE (override_mrr_amount, total_mrr, localized_subscription_start_date, localized_subscription_end_date, localized_version_start_date, localized_version_end_date, attributes) WHERE (((NOT (override_mrr_amount IS NULL)) AND (NOT ((override_mrr_amount = (0.0)::double precision) AND (override_mrr_amount IS NOT NULL)))) OR (NOT (total_mrr = (0.0)::double precision)))
```

Table Size: `customer` has `1.6M` rows, `subscription` 1.9M, `billing_cycle` 8.2M, and `product_version` 8.6M.

The query I am running is as follows:

```postgresql
WITH segmented_customer AS (SELECT * FROM customer WHERE integration_id = 430),
     segmented_subscription AS (SELECT * FROM subscription WHERE integration_id = 430),
     segmented_billing_cycle AS (SELECT * FROM billing_cycle WHERE integration_id = 430),
     segmented_product_version AS (SELECT * FROM product_version WHERE integration_id = 430)
SELECT segmented_customer.id                                       AS customer_id,
       segmented_customer.name                                     AS customer_name,
       segmented_product_version.override_mrr_amount               AS override_mrr_amount,
       segmented_product_version.total_mrr                         AS total_mrr,
       segmented_product_version.localized_subscription_start_date AS sub_start_ts,
       segmented_product_version.localized_subscription_end_date   AS sub_end_ts,
       segmented_product_version.localized_version_start_date      AS version_start_ts,
       segmented_product_version.localized_version_end_date        AS version_end_ts
FROM segmented_customer
         JOIN segmented_subscription ON segmented_customer.id = segmented_subscription.customer_id
         JOIN segmented_billing_cycle
              ON segmented_subscription.id = segmented_billing_cycle.subscription_id
         JOIN segmented_product_version
              ON segmented_billing_cycle.id = segmented_product_version.billing_cycle_id AND
                 ((override_mrr_amount IS NOT NULL AND
                   (NOT ((override_mrr_amount = 0) AND (override_mrr_amount IS NOT NULL)))) OR
                  (total_mrr != 0));
```

I know the CTEs don't appear to be doing anything, but in certain query patterns I filter data out in them, and I find it slightly easier to reason about what's going on this way.

This is the `EXPLAIN`: [here](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/52h7318dad59fdb9). I couldn't copy the full plan here directly because of character count limits.

The estimates I'm getting for the joins in particular are really bad: the planner estimates single digits of rows but in practice gets back thousands. A couple of questions:

1. How much does that bad planning matter? The joins still happen fairly quickly, although my understanding is that nested loops are best if one of the two joined tables is small, which neither is. I'm wondering if the planner would instead choose a Hash Join with better estimates and a sufficient `work_mem` parameter.
2. If I want to improve planning statistics, how do I even begin going about these complex conditions? I've read the [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/row-estimation-examples.html) on Row Estimation where they talk about joins, but the example given only involves 2 tables with one join key of the same name, and it's not clear to me how that translates to my situation.
3. There are bad estimates in some of the Index Only Scans too, but I'm less worried about those since I don't believe we can do better than an Index Only Scan, so as long as the planner picks that the estimate doesn't seem to matter.

I'm on Postgres 15.

Thanks in advance for any help! And happy to provide more information if that's necessary to understand the nature of the problem better.

The execution plan of the query:

```
Nested Loop (cost=22.13..1194.18 rows=1 width=89) (actual time=1.164..123.352 rows=17396 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=343763
  -> Nested Loop (cost=21.57..1190.17 rows=1 width=49) (actual time=0.486..31.595 rows=71646 loops=1)
     Buffers: shared hit=47191
       -> Merge Join (cost=21.02..1159.13 rows=7 width=49) (actual time=0.335..6.517 rows=3435 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared hit=3207
            -> Index Only Scan using customer_mrr_index on customer customer (cost=0.55..652.46 rows=3652 width=41) (actual time=0.156..2.624 rows=3341 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (customer.integration_id = 430)
               Buffers: shared hit=940
            -> Index Only Scan using subscription_mrr_index on subscription subscription (cost=0.55..489.36 rows=3246 width=30) (actual time=0.159..2.434 rows=3435 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (subscription.integration_id = 430)
               Buffers: shared hit=2267
       -> Index Only Scan using billing_cycle_mrr_index on billing_cycle billing_cycle (cost=0.56..4.42 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.002..0.005 rows=21 loops=3435)
          Index Cond: ((billing_cycle.integration_id = 430) AND (billing_cycle.subscription_id = subscription.id))
          Buffers: shared hit=43984
  -> Index Only Scan using pv_mrr_index on product_version product_version (cost=0.56..4 rows=1 width=56) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=71646)
     Index Cond: ((product_version.integration_id = 430) AND (product_version.billing_cycle_id = billing_cycle.id))
     Buffers: shared hit=296572
```

Comment: When was the last time those tables were analyzed?  (That’s **always** the first question in this situation.)